# Is the DataRecovery file by Windows?

Tags: virus

A few months ago, a few programs appeared that would occasionally pop up with unwanted advertisements and other content, so I'd like to delete them. I went to the shortcut properties and found that one of them came from something called DataRecovery.exe, and it was created on February 10th of this year which is far later than when I got my computer, but I might remember an update happening then which might have created it, so I'm not sure. Is this file common for other people? [image]

Comment: No; That isn't a Microsoft application.  You can verify this by viewing the properties and determine who signed the executable.  The software is likely legitimate, installed by the OEM, difficult to say one way or another without more information.

Comment: This is something you installed. It is not on my computers here.

Comment: rightclick on one of the exe's then properties then details might be useful. Add a screenshot

Comment: It looks too involved to be a virus (imho).. but that doesn't mean that it is good or that you want it on your system.

Comment: If you suspect a virus or similar then you should use a virus scanner and/or malware scanner.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - A virus does not typically have an uninstall functionality.  This is legitimate software that was installed.